# Limit Point of a Subset using Open Ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, product-space

I am studying analysis II and I have come across the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $(V, ||.||)$ be a normed space, $E$ any subset of V. Then a point $\vec{y} \in V$ is a limit point of $E$ iff $(B_{r}(\vec{y})\backslash \{\vec{y}\})\cap E \ne \emptyset$ for every $r$, where $B_{r}(\vec{y}) = \{ \vec{x} \in V: ||\vec{x} - \vec{y}|| < r \}$.

I have understood the proof for this lemma but intuitively I still have some problems with it. For example let $V = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = (-1,1)$. The limiting points of this set are $-1$ and $1$. Now, if we let $\vec{y} = 0$ and $r > 0$, $(B_{r}(\vec{0})\backslash \{\vec{0}\})\cap E \ne \emptyset$ as the intersection will include some part of $E$ which would mean $0$ is a limiting point as well (this reasoning can be applied to every point inside the set $E$). Clearly, there is something wrong with my reasoning but I can't seem to find it. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that what you said doesn't have to be the case. Take for example the set $A=(-1,1)\cup\{2\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. $2\in A$, but is certainly not a limit  point of $A$, since you can easily find a ball small enough (for example $B=B_{0.25}(2)$) s.t $B\setminus\{2\}\cap A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I have made a typo in the original question and now the lemma should be true and my question still stands.

Comment: its true that in your example every point in E is also limit point of E

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your reasoning. A point $x\in A$ can be a limit point as well. In normed spaces (more generally, in any metric space) a point $x\in A$ is a limit point iff there exists a non-constant sequence $x_n\neq x$ s.t $x_n\to x$. In your case, for every $x\in (-1,1)$ we can take $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enought s,t for every  $n\geq N$, $x+\frac{1}{n}\in (-1,1)$ and $x_n=x+\frac{1}{N+n}$ would be the desired sequence. Hence every $x\in (-1,1)$ is indeed a limit point.

Comment: I see, thanks for the response !